# Are singletons open sets?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I've recently been learning about metric spaces and one of the very important definitions are of open sets and open balls.
I have a question that was raised when reading on a website that a singleton in a metric space $(X,d)$ such as $[p]$ is considered to be an open set for example let the  set be $[0,1]$ and the metric be the standard metric is it true to say that the singleton $[1]$ is an open set? Since the $B_r$(1)=$[1]$ and this open ball is contained in the set.
However is this true for all singletons in the metric space $(\mathbb{R},d)$.
I'm new to metric spaces and I'm sure this is a very trivial question for most of you but its really confusing me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $\{1\}$ is not open in $[0,1]$ because any ball around $1$ will contain some number less than $1$.  More or less the same argument shows that in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard metric no singleton set is open. However there are metric spaces in which singleton sets can be open, for example if the metric is the discrete metric.

Comment: What about the singleton $[0.5]$

Comment: It is also not open for the same reason

Comment: if the singleton is isolated, then it's open.

Comment: You got $B_r(1)$ wrong...

Comment: In the space $[0,1]$ with the usual metric the ball $B_r(1)$  is the interval $(1-r,1]$. So it is not just $\{1\}$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You define a metric space by $(X,d)$ where $X$ is a non-empty set and $d$ is the distance function.  In the metric $(X,d),\,\, X$ is the universal set. So $X$ is always an open set. Now if you take $X$ as a singleton set then $X$ is always open.

Consider the Discrete metric space(trivial metric space) with $X=\mathbb Z$ or any subset of $\mathbb  Z$. If you take any $0<r<1$ then every singleton set consisting a single integer is open in $X$.

In the usual metric, (Euclidean metric of degree 1) $(\mathbb R,d)$ no singleton set is open.

Comment: is this because every point in the set of integers is an isolated point?

Answer (score 2):

No, the singleton set $\{1\}$, as a subset of the real line, is *not* an open set. Formally, this is because any open ball centered at $1$ *must* contain some number greater than and less than $1$.

When considering subsets of the real line, we can think of open sets as "having no borders;" they're the "opposite" of closed sets, which have a clearly defined boundary. It's the difference between the open interval $(a, b)$ and the closed interval $[a, b]$. One has endpoints, one doesn't.

A singleton set $\{x\}$ has boundaries, namely itself. It's the same as the closed interval $[x, x]$.

However, just note that this is not true in general metric spaces, namely the discrete metric space. In fact, a topology on any set $X$ is equal to the discrete topology on $X$ if and only if every singleton set of $X$ is open.

Answer (score 0):

Singleton sets on the real line are not open with the standard metric. To see this let $\{a\}$ be your singleton set, and construct a ball such that $B(a,r)\subseteq\{a\}$ or in other words with the metric we are working with the set of points $x$ such that $a-r<x<a+r\subseteq\{a\}$ but this is a contradiction since $r>0$